# Magento 2: Where does the oAuth verifier token come from

Tags: magento2, oauth, integration

Per the [developer documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#http-post), when making a request for an **access token**, you need to include a verifier token

> oauth_verifier. The verification code that is tied to the consumer and request token.

However, there's nothing in the documentation that mentions where this verifier token comes from.  I would presume it comes from the request for an **access token**, but the documentation doesn't reflect this.

Hoping somewhere here knows the answer ans saves me the headache of tracing out the oAuth process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I've got this one figured out.  When you authorize an integration, Magento makes a `POST` to the integration's callback URL.  This information includes the verifier token.

```
Called Array
(
    [oauth_consumer_key] => 2unvs7ccym............77kvlxx1rp
    [oauth_consumer_secret] => 1skp6............yy842a49xrjkaqb
    [store_base_url] => http://magento-2-0-4.dev/
    [oauth_verifier] => ku8wjnqxuxj98x0ruwf............4
)
```

Tangentially -- as the client/app owner, you use the consumer key and consumer secret to POST to `/oauth/token/request` and get a *request token*  and a *request token secret*.  You use the *request token* along with the *oauth verifier* when you request a **access token** from `/oauth/token/access`.  The *request token secret* is not used directly, but it is used **indirectly**.  The secret is used to sign the request made to `/oauth/token/access`.

Comment: How to programmatically 'Activate' and 'Authorize' an Integration? Please share some sample code.

Comment: How to programmatically 'Activate' and 'Authorize' an Integration? I have consumer key and consumer secret key. But where to get oauth_verifier? Please share some sample code.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110594/how-to-acquire-access-token-for-an-integration-in-magento2

Comment: Hi I solved it myself. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130567/magento-2-programmatically-create-activate-and-authorize-a-new-integration. But the concept you shared is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html) uses [OAuth 1.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html) based authentication for web APIs. At the first instance by looking on the documentation you will feel messed up. But if you have somewhat background of OAuth, you will easily guess what is next and why it is !!

Let us understand it step by step (You can skip the steps you have already done or understand to proceed):

Step 1: Login to Admin Panel and Go to Admin Panel -> System -> Integrations -> Add New Integration

Here provide the **Integration Details** and Check the **APIs** which you want to be accessible using this integration. [Here it is in more detail](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#activate).

Store the **CONSUMER_KEY** and **CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET**. We will use it in next step.

Step 2. Open REST Client (For Example: Postman Rest Client). Send the request

**POST** **http://mywebsite.com/oauth/token/request**

[image: /oauth/token/request snapshot]

Add the headers **Content-Type** and **Accept** with value **application/json**

And hit **[Send]**.

You will receive a response oauth_token=*`YOUR_OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN`*&oauth_token_secret=*`YOUR_OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET`*.

This is a temporary token you can use to communicate further.

> where this verifier token comes from. I would presume it comes from the request for an access token, but the documentation doesn't reflect this.

Step 3 [A]. Getting the access token. Here is the twist. The Magento framework relies on three types of requests;

1. Admin
2. Customer
3. Guest

Guest is the least privileged user, and can access only public/anonymous APIs. Let us suppose I am a customer, and I want to get authenticated. There comes a point in sudden **Show me you are my customer/Provide credentials**. Now customer needs to login.

**POST** **http://mywebsite.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token**

[image: Sign Using Rest Endpoint]

Move to **Body** tab and select **Raw** radio button and **JSON(application/json)**. Fill the login credential payload

{
"username":"myemail@domain.com",
"password":"mypassword"
}

Now click on **[Send]**.

***Voila !!!*** Here it is. The response you just received was **verifier_key**, that you were scratching head for. Now you may be feeling comfortable. And will guess the next step.

Step 3 [B]. [The current version of POSTMAN client is unable to set the **VERIFIER_KEY** in **Authorization** header](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/283). So you will need to use cURL client tool. These steps are some what cumbersome, but currently i felt it is the only way to demonstrate here.

**POST** **http://mywebsite.com/oauth/token/access**

In postmain rest client fill the form same as **Step 3 [A]**. Now click on **[code]** as shown in snapshot. From the pop up select **cURL** and click **Copy To Clipboard**.

[image: Retrieving the access token]

Open online **cURL** client tool. I have used http://onlinecurl.com/. Update the **Authorization** header by appending the **oauth_verifier** as below:

Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1482575080", oauth_nonce="2142790194", oauth_verifier="**`THE_OAUTH_VERIFIER_YOU_RECEIVED`**", oauth_token="your_oauth_request_token", oauth_signature="HMAC-SHA1_SIGNATURE_GENERATED_BY_POSTMAN_CLIENT"

The response will look like this:

oauth_token=**`access_oauth_token`**&oauth_token_secret=**`access_oauth_token_secret`**

Now you can use this token for furgther communication.

**Note:** Similarly **Admin** also gets authentication except he uses the **integration/admin/token** url to login.