# Integration ID is not specified or invalid when authorising

Tags: magento2, database, admin, magento2.4.1, integration

On a Magento v2.4.1 site, when trying to authorise an existing integration record, I'm receiving the error "Integration ID is not specified or is invalid".

[image: Magento admin - integrations page]

I verified that the record does have an ID set - it's set to 0. I'm assuming that is a valid ID?

I'm not sure where to start with diagnosis unfortunately - can anyone suggest where to start looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the ID of 0 is your problem. From `\Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit`:

```
$integrationId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_INTEGRATION_ID);
        if ($integrationId) {
            //stuff happens
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Integration ID is not specified or is invalid.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
```

I would expect PHP to interpret an integer of zero as a boolean of false, causing the condition to fail and throwing your error. I would expect any ID other than 0 to work. Since I don't see that the `integration.integration_id` field is a key for any other field, you may be able to change that value right in the database and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried updating the ID to 1 and authorise. This time I get "Internal error. Check exception log for details.". Exception.log isn't written to at all however... Weird.

Comment: After testing on my own instance, I believe changing the ID to a non-zero integer is the correct resolution to your OP, and that this is a new problem. I agree it's weird that a critical-level error isn't written to exception.log. For now, you may have success adding a temporary debug logger in Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit. If that's where the error is thrown, then inserting this between Lines 33 & 34 might at least get it into debug.log so you can see it: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->debug($e);

Comment: I figured out why no exeption.log was being generated - this was a completely unrelated issue. Entries in exception.log look like this "[2021-05-11 21:13:18] main.CRITICAL: The role wasn't found for the user. Verify the role and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\AuthorizationException(code: 0): The role wasn't found for the user. Verify the role and try again. at /home/cpaccount/public_html/m2dev/vendor/magento/module-authorization/Model/Acl/AclRetriever.php:86)"} []". There is only one role defined - administrator - all users are assigned to this.

Comment: I see that every integration record added is created with an integration_id set to 0. This is clearly incorrect. Is that column in the table integration not meant to be set to Auto Increment? I'm beginning to worry that the InnoDB table definition may be corrupted in some way.

Comment: As a workaround I managed to use [this code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130567/magento-2-programmatically-create-activate-and-authorize-a-new-integration) to create an authorised integration successfully. That said, I still need to figure out what the issue is here, and to resolve the question of whether or not `integration.integration_id` should be set to Auto Increment or not.

Comment: As the OP is answered but I have a knock-on issue, and query re the DB configuration of 'integration.integration_id', should I open a new question, assigning your answer as correct? Not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon regarding the 'work around'. Despite the record being authorised, it's impossible to edit it in order to view the keys. Once again, when trying this action, I get `Internal error. Check exception log for details.`. `exception.log` shows the same error as before `[2021-05-12 12:17:04] main.CRITICAL: The role wasn't found for the user. Verify the role and try again.`. I'm really not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think you can accept my answer and open a new question if necessary. I recommend first reviewing the docs (link below) on setting up a new integration. The 2016 code you found doesn't set up ACL roles (among other problems), which is what's tripping you up. This is what etc/integration/api.xml does. Also: `processIntegrationConfig` as used in the docs is technically deprecated, but seems the best way forward based on my hard-won experience. Here's the link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/create-integration.html. Ping me if you get stuck again and open a new question.

Comment: Also, as a hint for parsing your way through the integration doc: there should only be three files you need to create or touch to generate a new integration: etc/integration/api.xml, etc/integration/config.xml, and
Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php (or UpdateData.php). Review those against the instructions, and good luck.

Comment: This was happening on a 'live' site, having copied the db from a 'test' domain. Seeing that  the test site was functioning properly when authorising integrations, re-migrating the db fixed the issues we were having. Clearly the first time oath and / or integration tables were corrupted in some way. Anyway, thank you so much for your assistance and time trying to figure out what was wrong here.

Comment: Great! How often things are fixed by "turning it off and on again..."