# Neither Token nor Oauth API Authentication are working Magento 2.2.3

Tags: rest-api, oauth, magento2.2.3, token

Upon activating Oauth in Magento admin, there is no request sent to the callback URL.  If I try to setup normal token authentication, there are no tokens provided.

I followed the [documentation for oauth.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html)  Magento will call the URL at "Identity link URL" but it will not call the URL at "Callback URL."  I setup the script at the Callback URL to send me an email when it is called. I can copy/paste the Callback URL from Magento admin into Postman to confirm the script at the URL works so I am sure the URL is correct and the script will take action when it is called.  I am certain Magento is not sending anything to the Callback URL after selecting Activate, selecting Allow, getting expected redirect from Identity link URL, and selecting OK.  My server never saw a request at the URL entered in Callback URL.

I also tried setting up basic token authentication following [the token authentication documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html).  This is basically the same process but Callback URL and Identity link URL are left blank.  Again, I hit Authorize and Allow but only the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret blanks are filled in where the documentation suggests Magento should also provide tokens.  What I see are the Access Token and Access Token Secret remain blank.

I have tried deleting values in oauth token table.  That had no impact.

I tried using Postman to post to POST mywebsite.com/oauth/token/request [using the guidance provided in this post.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110026/magento-2-where-does-the-oauth-verifier-token-come-from).  I am certain I had the Oauth 1.0 fields filled out exactly as described in the post.  However, Magento returned

> oauth_problem=oauth_consumer_key+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_signature+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_signature_method+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_nonce+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_timestamp+is+a+required+field

There is nothing in the magento/var/log/ logfiles that reflect any of the activity associated with setting up the APIs.

I was using the API successfully in the past by requesting a token using /rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token with a username and password.  At some point that stopped working and I actually don't recall where I got the username and password from as it is an odd looking username that I don't see in the list of users.  I am trying to set up the Oauth process in its place but having no luck at all.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was I was attempting to use a callback URL that required basic authentication.   I did not notice this when I tested the URL because my computer had already authenticated.   I changed the callback URL to a valid URL that did not require authentication and everything now works as expected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you meant by basic authentication? I'm stuck in the exact situation like you were once. Thank you

Comment: For signature generation refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358743/how-to-call-magento-2-oauth-1-0-api-for-services-without-callback-identity-url