# Unable to get access_token for Magento2.0

Tags: magento2, oauth, token

I am doing **OAuth1 authentication for Magento2.0**. I am referring this doc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html.

**I am trying to do this using Postman**. I have followed steps mentioned in : [Magento 2: Where does the oAuth verifier token come from](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110026/magento-2-where-does-the-oauth-verifier-token-come-from?rq=1)

**1. Get request token:** I could get it using Consumer key and consumer secret generated by integration and POST /oauth/token/request.

Response was: oauth_token=xxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxx

[image]

**2. Get oauth_verifier:** Got the oauth_verifier using POST http://mywebsite.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token.
Used consumer key,consumer secret, request token and request token secret along with payload: { "username":"myemail@domain.com", "password":"mypassword" }
[image]

**3. Get access token:** When I try to get the access token I face some issues. Added oauth_verifier to Authorization Header.

**Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1482575080", oauth_nonce="2142790194", oauth_verifier="THE_OAUTH_VERIFIER_YOU_RECEIVED", oauth_token="your_oauth_request_token", oauth_signature="HMAC-SHA1_SIGNATURE_GENERATED_BY_POSTMAN_CLIENT"**

I tried POST /oauth/token/access by 2 ways:

**1. Using online curl tool:** I got "oauth_problem=OAuth+version+%5C%221.0%5C+is+not+supported" error.
[image]

**2. Using Postman:** I got "oauth_problem=Token+verifier+and+verifier+token+do+not+match" error.
[image]

I searched for these errors but could not get much information.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you generated oauth token using integration ?

Comment: I could generate the access token and access token secret using integration (keeping the Callback and Identity link URL blank). But I  dont want to use that way. I want to use POST APIs to get request token and access token. I was able to get request token and oauth_verifier but not able to get the oauth_token.

Comment: There are 2 types of token 1. Admin and 2. Customer

Comment: You can fetch those token by POSTMAN and curl

Comment: are you looking for those token ? if yes, then i post an answer

Comment: I am looking for how to get the access token using Postman or curl command. I am getting errors when I try to get access token using POST /oauth/token/access.

Comment: Yeah , got your point.

Comment: I am sharing a script to get Customer token using POSTMAN.

Comment: Okay. I want the admin token.

Answer (score 1):

**Endpoint**

```
POST http://<host>/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token
```

**Header**

```
Content-Type application/json
```

**Payload**

```
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "123123q"
}
```

**Response**

Magento returns the admin’s access token.

- This token must be specified in the authorization header of every
  call that requires admin permissions.

Comment: Yes. But I thought further I would get an access token. I could not get it. I want the access token. Could you refer the doc which I have mentioned in the question. I have followed those steps. But last step to get the access token is giving me error.

Comment: Are you using POSTMAN ? if yes then please share the sceen shot so i can help you out.

Comment: Yes I am using Postman. Will attach screen shot and modify question.